# MariaDB loop for items in a list

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I want to loop through a pre-generated list of values and for each item i want to insert some data into a table.

```sql
DELIMITER //
START TRANSACTION;
FOR myitem IN (1, 5, 6, 14, 73, 811)
DO
    INSERT INTO `TestTable` (`userid`, `info`) VALUES (myitem, 'test input')'
END FOR;
ROLLBACK;
//
```

I'm getting a syntax error at the start of the list. (using MariaDB 10.7 and for loops are working with `1..5`)

I have checked the docs [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-for-loop/) but it does not show using a defined list.

Answer (score 1):

`FOR IN()` loop only supports sequences, lists can be used only in `IN()` condition.

A simple pure SQL solution would be to move the values into WHERE condition:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable(userid, info) 
  SELECT seq, "test_input" FROM seq_1_to_811 
  WHERE seq IN (1, 5, 6, 14, 73, 811);
```

A better and fast approach would be to handle this in a client application using batch execution:

Python example:

```
ids= [(1,),(5,),(6,),(14,),(73,),(811,)];
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO TestTable(userid,info) VALUES (?, 'test')", ids);
```